# Do techrolls/getup rolls stale dodges?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

When in free fall, you can press shield when you're about to hit the ground to perform a [tech](https://www.ssbwiki.com/tech) in Smash. If you're holding a direction, this will turn into a [techroll](https://www.ssbwiki.com/tech#Rolling_tech)--you'll use a similar animation to a dodge roll.

However, as of Smash Ultimate, [dodges will stale](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/344233/222207) the more you use them. Does a techroll count as a dodge in the sense that it'll stale your dodges?

Will a [floor recovery](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Floor_recovery) roll or a [getup roll](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Edge_recovery) act the same way?

Comment: Your statement about techrolls being the same as dodge rolls is incorrect; see Marth/Lucina/etc: their techrolls are an actual roll but their dodge rolls are a sidestep-type thing; totally different.

Comment: @firedraco good catch. I updated my wording.

Answer (score 2):

The current evidence suggests that only forward rolls, backward rolls, sidesteps, and air dodges are part of the dodge-staling system. Techrolls (any direction), getup rolls (any direction), and edge rolls are not.

This is based on the fact that in the location where dodge staling numbers are stored, only `escape_n` (sidestep), `escape_f` (forward roll), `escape_b` (backward roll), and `escape_air` (airdodge) have values. Other roll-like options (`down_forward_u`, `down_back_u`, `down_forward_d`, `down_back_d`, `passive_stand_f`, `passive_stand_b`, `cliff_escape`) do not.

Comment: Do you have a link to the code that you're talking about or some other visualization? Also what do you mean when you say these variables (if that's what they are?) "have values?"

Comment: By "have values" I pretty much mean "they exist"; only the four basic dodges have staling data, the situational ones do not. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to link to the source (it's a private document).

Comment: Hmm you have my upvote, but it's difficult to mark this as the accepted answer when it feels like I'd just be taking your word for it. If you can't link the source can you perhaps post the relevant snippets where you see this happening?